# How do you control the amount of times the void loop loops per second?

Tags: arduino-uno, serial, pins

```
int firstAnalogPin = 0;         
int secondAnalogPin = 5;  
int firstVal = 0;  
int secondVal = 0;  
void setup(){

  Serial.begin(9600);          //  setup serial

}

void loop(){

firstVal = analogRead(firstAnalogPin); 
   // read the input pin

secondVal = analogRead(secondAnalogPin); 
   // read the input pin

Serial.print(firstVal); 

Serial.print("\t");

Serial.println(secondVal);

}
```

Basically, I want to know how to convert from the baud rate to the number of times `loop()` runs per second. How do I control the number of `loop()`s per second?

Comment: You don't. See the answers. Assuming you found that it looped (say) 1000 times per second, and then you added code to do something, knowing that, then the extra code would make it loop 900 times per second. So you allow for that, and then it loops 800 times per second. This is not the way to go about it.

Comment: If you don't need precise control, you can simple add a `delay` at the end of the `loop`.

Comment: how to set code while one loop is completed their work, then after the next loop is executed.

Answer (score 3):

The number of times `loop()` runs every second depends on the time taken for the execution of the instructions *within* `loop()`. For instance, in your code, the time taken for one `loop()` is roughly equal to the time taken for the MCU to execute all the statements in `loop()` (more specifically, the time taken for each operation or function from call to return): in your case, the time taken for the `Serial.print()`s + the time taken for the `analogRead()`s (not considering any interrupts between statements).

That said, you generally don't want to control the interval between `loop()`s; I assume you actually want to control the interval between the execution of certain operations within your `loop()`. Say, you want to set the time between executions of `analogRead(0)` to 500 ms. This can be done like this:

```
#define INTERVAL 500   // time between reads
unsigned long lastRead = 0;

void setup(){
  Serial.begin(9600);          //  setup serial
}

void loop(){
  //....your other code....

  if (millis() - lastRead >= INTERVAL){  // if INTERVAL has passed
    val = analogRead(0);
    lastRead = millis(); 
    Serial.println(val);
    //...anything else
  }

  //...your other code...
}
```

With this code, you now have about 2 `analogRead` samples every second. Of course, this is only useful if `loop()` runs faster than your chosen interval. If there are function calls, or any operations otherwise, in `loop()` (within or outside the IF block) that always take more time than your interval, then this code would serve no purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to control how often the sensor is polled and printed to SD card, I would suggest you check out Blink Without Delay https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkWithoutDelay it would be a much cleaner way than trying to slow down the loop to a specified time.

Answer (score 0):

Marcello Romani's [SimpleTimer library](http://playground.arduino.cc/Code/SimpleTimer) was made for this kind of problem. You let `loop()` run as fast as possible but only maintain the timers and do other *short* tasks. The timer library runs your periodic tasks when necessary:

```
#include <SimpleTimer.h>
SimpleTimer timer;         // creates a set of timers

// A timer call-back function - there can be more than one
void onTimer(void){
   ;   // do stuff here, keep it short
}

void setup(void){
   ;   // Serial.begin() and other setup

   timer.setInterval(1000L, onTimer); // set a 1-sec repeating timer
}

void loop(void){
   timer.run();   // updates timers, maybe calls a callback func
   ;              // whatever other loop code
}
```